How can I non destructively remove this ceiling to run electrical wires?
I have a basement with this ceiling in part of it. I need to run Romex for the first floor, but I also don't dislike this ceiling enough to warrant destroying it. Is there some way to non destructively remove it? Also, what type of ceiling is this, so that I can better research this?
When I feel the texture of this ceiling it feels very light and somewhat crumbly, like extra brittle cardboard. I also can't find any visible fastening parts to remove. Lastly, it seems to be made out of panels that are much larger than the visible squares because pushing up on it reveals seams between these panels. This house was built in 1907, but I do not think that this ceiling was original.




Before you do anything with them, I'd send off a sample to test for asbestos.  Cheap, fairly fast, and then you know how safe it is to disturb them.

Ceiling tiles.  Guessing about 12x12 if that is a four foot light.
They are made from fibres(wood like) and held up with staples driven in to a large flange on one end, with tongue and groove to hold the next tile.
The corners will be the best place to start.  If there is moulding, then easy to remove and remove one tile.
The staples are small, driven in with a hand staple gun, just the big boy size from common desk paper staplers.

Search for 1x1 interlocking ceiling tile.  These are easy to find and maybe $3 each so if you damage some you can replace them.  Your replacements may not match perfectly but look for the closest match for the pattern of little holes in the old ones.
Use a knife with a new blade to cut the tongues off any tile, then try to gingerly remove fasteners and slide apart the tongue and groove of adjacent ones as you go.  If you find them all breaking randomly you may prefer to cut them cleanly instead, then later devise a creative way to replace them.
